# Programmatically creating an image in Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'd like to create an image (say a [nativeImage](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/native-image.md)) from a JS array containing raw pixel RGB values.

I tried creating a nativeImage like this:

`const buf = Buffer.from([[0, 0, 255], [0, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [255, 0, 0]])
const img = nativeImage.createFromBuffer(buf, {width: 2, height: 2})
...
<img width={16} height={16} src={img.toDataURL()} />`

But it seems like the image always turns out black.

Some online resources seem to indicate that the `createFromBuffer` call expects the buffer to contain PNG encoded data (I couldn't really tell from the API ref).

Is there a way to go directly from pixel values to an image?

Answer (score 0):

The buffer should contain values alpha values too, not just RGB (e.g,. [A0,R0,G0,B0, A1,R1,G1,B1, ... ]).

For example:

```
const buf = Buffer.from([255,0,0,255, 0,255,0,255, 0,0,255,255, 0,0,0,255])
const img = nativeImage.createFromBuffer(buf, {width: 2, height: 2})
```

This will generate an image like so:

[image]